# Invalid DateTime error while trying to insert datetime value into BigQuery from Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

We wrote a Google Data Flow code that inserts  a value into a bigquery 
 table whose column is of type DateTime. 
 The logic was running fine most of the times.
 But suddenly we get Invalid DateTime issue.

```
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"generic::out_of_range: Invalid datetime string \"2017-09-26T21:16\"
```

It is unclear how and why the above value is invalid.
We see that it is adhering to DateTime datatype mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types

Also it remains unclear why it is throwing this error only on occasions.

We wrote a custom Transformation code that extends DoFn
The ProcessElement code goes like this

```
 public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {

    TableRow tableRow = c.element();
    try {
       // do some processing then 
      tableRow.set("PredictedDate",**LocalDateTime.now().toString()**);
      c.output(tableRow);
    }catch(Exception exc){
        LOG.error("Exception while processing and hence not attempting to write to bigquery");
    }
} 

enter code here
```

It was working fine but fails occasionally during night times(US Central timezone).
Can you please help us find the root cause.

Comment: Instead of `2017-09-26T21:16`, the string should be `2017-09-26T21:16:00`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format described for [DateTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime-type) indicates that a seconds field is required.

`YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]]`

Specifically, note that the second `S` is not enclosed in square brackets making it optional.

Comment: Thanks. Also i was using LocalDateTime.now().toString() which seems to discard seconds when the seconds is zero.Used ISO formatter to set it right.Thanks for the help

Comment: I had 7 subseconds 2018-04-22T18:15:54.9046289, used `CONVERT(DATETIME2(6), CreatedDate)` to get it down to 6 subseconds  2018-04-22T18:15:54.904629

Comment: Too bad that ```DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]]")``` cannot handle the official BigQuery pattern. ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: T```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I'm retrieving time in timestamp and make convertion to the string:

```
new Date(event_timestamp_ms).toISOString().slice(0, -1);
```

Since DATETIME doesn't contain information about timezone, if helps to remove Z symbol from UTC format.